# Search for string in PDS and exclude results using JCL

Tags: search, jcl

I am trying to do the following:

1) Search members of a PDS for a string.
2) Exclude the members with the above mentioned string and get a list of members.

I want to do this using a JCL or any other mainframe tool or utility.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the ISPF [Search-For utility](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.f54u200/search.htm), which can also be [executed in batch](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.f54u200/ssfjibm.htm).

You can also use the [SRCHFOR](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r13.f54rs00/pdfmemlist.htm) command at an ISPF member listing screen, then sort by the prompt column which indicates which members had matches.

Comment: With what we know, I think this is it. Same answer on the other site, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably much better ways of doing this but this should work for you.
Copy the following JCL and replace:

- **your-job-car-info** with whatever your job card needs
- **pds-to-search** with the name of the PDS you want to search
- **temp-pds-name** with a valid PDS name that won't duplicate anything you already have
- **string-to-search-for** with the string you want to search PDS members for

The list of PDS members that do not contain **string-to-search-for** will be listed under DD **LISTING**,
which you can redirect wherever appropriate.

The first job step (SEARCH) invokes the ISPF SEARCHFOR utility, to identify all the PDS members that contain the string.
The second step (LSTPDS) invokes the TSO LISTDS utility to list all members of the PDS. The third step (REXXPGM) writes a little
REXX procedure to a temporary PDS for use in the next step. The last step (LSTMBR) runs the REXX procedure to build the LISTING dataset
and deletes the temporary files built along the way.

If one were smart enough, I think ICETOOL could probably replace the final 2 steps (but what the heck... Actually I did find a better process, see next JCL after this one)

```
//LOOKFOR JOB your-job-card-info
//*====================================================================
//SEARCH  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=(SRCHCMP,'ANYC')
//NEWDD  DD DSN=pds-to-search,DISP=SHR
//OUTDD DD DSN=&&SRCH,DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//            AVGREC=K,
//            SPACE=(133,(5,5)),
//            DCB=(LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=133,RECFM=FB)
//SYSIN  DD *
SRCHFOR  'string-to-search-for'
/*
//*====================================================================
//LSTPDS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01
//SYSTSPRT DD DSN=&&MBRS,DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//            AVGREC=K,
//            SPACE=(80,(5,5)),
//            DCB=(LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=80,RECFM=FB)
//SYSTSIN  DD *
 LISTDS 'pds-to-search' MEMBERS
/*
//REXXPDS  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD *
 ALLOCATE DSN('temp-pds-name') NEW KEEP -
          DSORG(PO) RECFM(F,B) LRECL(80) -
          AVGREC(U) SPACE(80,100) DIR(5) DSNTYPE(PDS)
/*
//*====================================================================
//REXXPGM  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD *
 REPRO INFILE(REXXPROG) OUTDATASET('temp-pds-name(MBRLIST)')
/*
//REXXPROG DD *
'EXECIO * DISKR SRCH(FINIS STEM X.'
FND = ''
DO I = 1 TO X.0
  IF WORD(X.I, 3) = 'STRING(S)' THEN FND = FND WORD(X.I, 1)
END
DROP X.
'EXECIO * DISKR MBRS(FINIS STEM X.'
MBRS = 0
DO I = 1 TO X.0 - 2
  IF MBRS & WORDPOS(WORD(X.I, 1), FND) = 0 THEN
     QUEUE WORD(X.I,1)
  ELSE
     IF X.I = '--MEMBERS--' THEN MBRS = 1 
END
'EXECIO * DISKW LISTING(FINIS'
RETURN
/*
//*====================================================================
//LISTMBR  EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM=('%MBRLIST')
//SYSEXEC  DD DSN=NXB123.JUNK,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//SRCH     DD DSN=&&SRCH,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//MBRS     DD DSN=&&MBRS,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//LISTING  DD SYSOUT=A
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=A
//SYSTSIN  DD *
/*
//
```

**And this an even better answer...** Just took a while to get there

```
//MYJOB JOB your-job-card-info
//SEARCH  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=(SRCHCMP,'LNFMTO')
//NEWDD  DD DSN=pds-to-search,DISP=SHR
//OUTDD DD DSN=&&SRCH,DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE),
//            AVGREC=K,
//            SPACE=(133,(5,5)),
//            DCB=(LRECL=133,BLKSIZE=133,RECFM=FB)
//SYSIN  DD *
 SRCHFOR  'string-to-search-for'
/*
//STEP02  EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTMSG DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN DD DSN=&&SRCH,DISP=(OLD,DELETE,DELETE)
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY -
 INCLUDE COND=(30,6,CH,EQ,C'    0 ') -
 OUTREC  FIELDS=(1,8)
/*
```

The key is the `LNFMTO` paramter fed to ISRSUPC. This parameter tells ISRSUPC to list only those members where
the search string was not found. Exactly what was asked for. The next step just
formats the results from the previous step. The list of members that do not contain the search
string are listed in `SYSOUT` which can be redirected where needed.

Comment: @poornimas This is the one you should work with. You should Accept this answer, and review your other answers. Once you have enough reputation, you should also Upvote answers which have assisted you. That is if you come back...

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: "punch" the whole PDS, in unsorted order, to a "flat" file; use JOINKEYS with data prepared using SS, for Sub-String, field type.

```
//PUNCHIT EXEC PGM=IEBPTPCH 
//SYSUT1 DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=your.pds 
//SYSUT2 DD  DSN=output.dataset,RECFM=FB,LRECL=81,otherstuffyouneed
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN DD * 
 PUNCH TYPORG=PO 
/*
```

After that, a JOINKEYS step using SORT:

```
//FINDMISS EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 
  JOINKEYS F1=INA,FIELDS=(1,8,A) 
  JOINKEYS F2=INB,FIELDS=(82,8,A) 
  JOIN UNPAIRED,F1,ONLY 
/*                                                             
//JNF1CNTL DD * 
  INCLUDE COND=(2,13,CH,EQ,C'MEMBER NAME') 
  INREC BUILD=(15,8)
/* 
//JNF2CNTL DD * 
  INCLUDE COND=(2,13,CH,EQ,C'MEMBER NAME', 
             OR,2,72,SS,EQ,C'yoursearchvalue') 
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(2,13,CH,EQ,C'MEMBER NAME'),
                    PUSH=(82:15,8)), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,13,CH,EQ,C'MEMBER NAME'), 
                    OVERLAY=(82:8X)) 
/*
//INA DD DISP=SHR,DSN=YOUR.PUNCHED.FILE 
//INB DD DISP=SHR,DSN=YOUR.PUNCHED.FILE (yes, exactly the same one)
```

Then processes the punched file, reading it twice in the same step, and using JOINKEYS to "match" one extract from the file to another extract from the file.

On INA via JNF1CNTL it extracts all the member names.

On INB via JNF2CNTL it extracts all the member names, plus all data-lines which match the required search. IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP is then used to mark each data line that has matched with the member-name they are part of, and the member-name itself gets given a blank member-name.

The JOINKEYS then match on the member-name keys. All those from INA via JNF1CNTL which do not match are those members which do not contain the searched-for string. Both files require sorting, which happens by default for each JOINKEYS statement.

This will work with DFSORT. With SyncSort it will depend whether your installation supports JNFnCNTL files or not (you have to try it, it is not documented). If you do not have JNFnCNTL support, it would require two earlier, separate, steps to extract the data.

Comment: Thanks @NealB, I must have lost the EXEC when highlighting the stepname to change it... The `/*` I never use (nor `END` for SORT). If not needed, they only introduce a, very small, chance of a typo (very small since they'll be copied, rather than typed... mostly). When "spacing" steps for easier reading, I go for `//*`.

Comment: Fair enough... Ditch the `/*` if it bugs you. One other observation though, what happens when the first 13 characters of a record from a PDS member have `MEMBER NAME ` as data? Would your process pick up what follows as a new member name?

Comment: @NealB, I don't mind them being there. It is a good point about the false hit. I'm going to check the docs on IEBPTPCH - I just stole a random sample and I think it can be made less easy to get the false hit.

Comment: Have a look at my second attempt at this, I stumbled across the `LNFMTO` parm for ISRSUPC and it pretty much nails what the OP is looking for. Learn something new every day...